# PHP: search recursively for specific file extensions, exclude certain directories

Tags: php

Clueless PHP coder here. I have a photo library structured as follows:

```
DIR
  thumbnails
file1.jpeg
file1.NEF
file2.JPG
  SUBDIR
   thumbnails
  file3.jpeg
  file3.ARW
  file4.NEF
```

I'd like my PHP script to find all `*.jpeg` files in all directories, except `thumbnails`.

Thanks to my amazing copy-pasting skills, I came up with this:

```
function rsearch($dir, $pattern_array) {
  $return = array();
  $iti = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($dir, FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS);
  foreach(new RecursiveIteratorIterator($iti) as $file){
    if (in_array(strtolower(array_pop(explode('.', $file))), $pattern_array)){
                    $return[] = $file;
    }
  }
  return $return;
}

$files = rsearch("photos", array('jpeg', 'JPEG'));
```

It works, but it also returns result from all `thumbnails` subdirectories. And I can't for the live of me figure out how to exclude them. I'd be grateful for any suggestions.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Just check if file path starts with `thumbnails` path and skip them

Answer (score 2):

You just have to verify the `$iti` to check if its a file or a directory, if its a directory make sure its not one called `thumbnails`. Also cleaned up your file extension verification method.

```
function rsearch($dir, $pattern_array) {
    $return = array();
    $iti = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($dir, FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS);

    foreach(new RecursiveIteratorIterator($iti) as $file => $details){

        if(!is_file($iti->getBasename()) && ($iti->getBasename() != "thumbnails")) {

            $file_ext = pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        
            if (in_array(strtolower($file_ext), $pattern_array)){
                $return[] = $file;
            }

        }
    }

    return $return;
}

$files = rsearch("photos", array('jpg', 'jpeg'));

print_r($files);
```